# mySQL - Load GTFS Data

Tags: php, mysql, gtfs

I was wondering if anyone has had any success loading GTFS data to a mySQL database. I've looked all over the place for a good tutorial but I can't find anything that has been helpful.

Comment: I've done it before but some of the files were huge and required either command line importing or MySQL big dump

Answer (score 2):

I succeed in importing GTFS files into MySQL.

### Step 1: Create a database

```
CREATE DATABASE gtfs
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
    DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

### Step 2: Create tables

For instance, create the table `stops` for `stops.txt`,

```
-- stop_id,stop_code,stop_name,stop_lat,stop_lon,location_type,parent_station,wheelchair_boarding
CREATE TABLE `stops` (
        stop_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    stop_code VARCHAR(255),
    stop_name VARCHAR(255),
    stop_lat DECIMAL(8,6),
    stop_lon DECIMAL(8,6),
    location_type INT(2),
    parent_station VARCHAR(255),
    wheelchair_boarding INT(2),
    stop_desc VARCHAR(255),
    zone_id VARCHAR(255)
);
```

### Step 3: Load local data

For instance, load the local file `stops.txt` into the table `stops`,

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'stops.txt' INTO TABLE stops FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

The complete source code with an example is placed on GitHub ([here](https://github.com/sparkandshine/data_analysis/tree/master/traces/tisseo_toulouse_gtfs)). Make some slight changes for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this one :

https://code.google.com/p/gtfsdb/

The website says :

GTFS (General Transit Feed Specification) Database

Python code that will load GTFS data into a relational database, and Sql/Geo-Alchemy ORM bindings to the GTFS tables in the gtfsdb.

The gtfsdb project's focus is on making GTFS data available in a programmatic context for software developers. The need for the gtfsdb project comes from the fact that a lot of developers start out a GTFS-related effort by first building some amount of code to read GTFS data (whether that's an in-memory loader, a database loader, etc...); gtfsdb can hopefully reduce the need for such drudgery, and give developers a starting point beyond the first step of dealing with GTFS in .csv file format.

Answer (score 0):

I actually used the following link as a base and converted it to a script, worked like a charm

http://steffen.im/php-gtfs-to-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I created the table structures first.

Then load the data via the following command in mysql command console

load data local infile '/media/sf_Downloads/google_transit/stops.txt' into table stop fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n' ignore 1 rows;

This loads the stops.txt into stop table. ignore the first row (heading) in the stops.txt file.

'/media/...' is just the path to the file, where I extract the gtfs data.

Answer (score 0):

I loaded the GTFS data into a SQLite database through the following commands:

Create a new SQLite Database named *test.sqlite3*

```
sqlite3 test.sqlite3
```

Set the mode to csv

```
sqlite> .mode csv
```

Import Each File into a corresponding table with import command *.import FILE TABLE*

```
sqlite> .import agency.txt agency
sqlite> .import calendar.txt calendar
...
sqlite> .import stops.txt stops
```

Now your database should be loaded

Answer (score 0):

Hi looking for something similar and still not getting an easy way to do it. I am going to give a try [GTFS to MySQl using Python](https://github.com/sbma44/py-gtfs-mysql)

Answer (score -1):

According to [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/), a GTFS feed is basically a zip file containing text files. You should be able to store it in your MySQL database using a BLOB type field. But this isn't recommended. You should store it as a file on your server's disk and then store the file's name/path into a regular text/varchar field in your database.